# Understanding unsolved metavariables and yellow highlighting in agda

Tags: typechecking, agda

In the agda docs, I read that when "some meta-variable other than the goals cannot be solved the code will be highlighted in yellow"

I'm trying to understand this in a somewhat degenerate case.

If I define a regular product type then a stupid program works fine.

```
data _==_ {l}{X : Set l}(x : X) : X -> Set where
  refl : x == x

data prod (A B : Set) : Set where
  _,,_ : A → B → prod A B

fst' : {A B : Set} → prod A B → A
fst' (x ,, x₁) = x

stupid : fst' (3 ,, 3) == 3
stupid = refl
```

However, if I use a product as a special case of a dependent product, I get the yellow highlighting for `stupid''''`.  Specifically, the `fst` and and the second `3` are highlighed yellow.  Why do all the other `stupid*`'s work except for `stupid''''`?  Are there any general tips for debugging yellow highlighting errors in agda?

```
record Sg {l}(S : Set l)(T : S -> Set l) : Set l where
  constructor _,_
  field
    fst : S
    snd : T fst
open Sg public

_*_ : forall {l} -> Set l -> Set l -> Set l
S * T = Sg S \ _ -> T

infixr 40 _,_
infixr 20 _*_

threethree : Nat * Nat
threethree = 3 , 3

three : Nat
three = fst threethree

stupid'' : three == 3
stupid'' = refl

stupid''' : fst (threethree) == 3
stupid''' = refl

--here's the yellow highlighting
stupid'''' : fst (3 , 3) == 3
stupid'''' = refl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--here's the yellow highlighting
stupid'''' : fst (3 , 3) == 3
stupid'''' = refl
```

This is because Agda can't infer the type of `(3 , 3)` to supply it to `fst`.

"But that's just `Nat * Nat`!"

Not necessarily, it can be

```
Sg Nat \n -> if n == 3 then Nat else Bool
```

or any other weird type that gives `Nat` as a type of the second element whenever the first element is `3` and does something completely different in all other cases.

And Agda's unification machinery always either finds a unique solution or gives up.

You've asked Agda to solve the following unification problem:

```
_T 3 =?= Nat
```

and clearly there are way too many different `_T`s that return `Nat` when the argument is `3`.

> Why do all the other `stupid*`'s work except for `stupid''''`

Because in all the other ones there's no ambiguity:

- in `stupid` the type of the second element does not depend on the first element (due to the definition of `prod`)
- in other cases you explicitly specify the type of the argument (via a standalone declaration)

Comment: so is there any  way to include the (Nat * Nat) information in `stupid''''` without adding an auxiliary `threethree` or something of that nature

Comment: @WarrickMacmillan you can annotate the tuple with its type as in `test : fst (_ * _ ∋ 3 , 3) == 3` (where `_∋_` is defined in the stdlib [like that](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/041fd896be22045262fb5d53ef10fc779f827bcc/src/Function/Base.agda#L170)). Or you can define a non-dependent version of `_,_` and use it. Or you can resolve `T` manually: `test : fst {T = \_ -> Nat} (3 , 3) == 3`. Or you can define a non-dependent `fst`: `fst' : forall {l} {A : Set l} {B : Set l} -> A * B -> A` and use it.